# How do I delete all of the text on the screen - Python

Tags: python

I make stop-motion animation films, and I wanted to see if I could do something like that with coding. I have this:

```
import sleep
print('   _  ')
print('  |_| ')
print('  -|-  ')
print('   |  ')
print('  /\  ')
time.sleep(.1)
print('   _  ')
print('  |_| ')
print('  -|/  ')
print('   |  ')
print('  /\  ')
```

So essentially, it will look like the stick figure is waving. But, this of course only prints out the 2nd stick figure below it. I am wondering how I can make it delete the first one, then replace it with the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on linux you want `os.system('clear')`

on windows you want `os.system('CLS')`

if you mean to clear the idle window, that's not possible without some sort of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('cls||clear')
```

Sleeping 1 or 2 seconds before clearing will be better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Formatting help for SO's flavor of markdown is [here](/help/formatting). Remember that the answers you write will remain here for people of the future to read if they encounter the same problem. Keeping this in mind, it's _always_ better to include all relevant details in your answer instead of posting a brief, code-only answer or one that contains unjustified statements, such as _"Sleeping 1 or 2 seconds before clearing..."_: why would this be better?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of dynamic printouts / displays, I would suggest using IPython's [display module](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html).

> **Note:** I've edited my answer (after seeing many of the responses here) to allow for terminal as well as notebook display choices...

```py
# Create your figures
fig_1 = """
   _
  |_|
  -|-
   |
  /\\
"""

fig_2 = """
   _
  |_|
  -|/
   |
  /\\
"""


# Now the code / display
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import time
import os

notebook = False
display(fig_1)
time.sleep(.1)
if notebook: clear_output(wait=True)
else: os.system('clear')
display(fig_2)
```

A fancier way of doing this:

```
# A fancier way of doing it
def display_animated_figs(all_figs:list, sleep_s:float, notebook=False):
    """Displays each figure in the list of figs,
    while waiting between to give `animated feel`

    notebook: (bool) are you operating in a notebook? (True) Terminal? (False)
    """
    
    for i, fig in enumerate(all_figs):
        # Always clear at start...
        # Allow for notebooks or terminal
        if notebook:
            clear_output(wait=True)
        else:
            os.system('clear')
        # After the first figure, wait
        if i>0:
            time.sleep(sleep_s)
            
        display(fig)
   
   # All done, nothing to return  

# Now execute
my_figs = [fig_1, fig_2]
display_animated_figs(my_figs, 0.1, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 methods:

method 1.
print empty lines. this code just prints '' 50 times so anything printed earlier will go off the screen

```py
[print('') for x in range(50)]
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), basically the same thing as a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

method 2.
prints the newline char (an enter) * 50, that's just 50 new lines

```py
print('\n' * 50)
```

(yes you can do * and + on strings with python. if you are planning on doing more with python I would highly recommend looking into that)

method 3. cls command. this will call the cls (or clear screen) command. you do have to import os though.

```py
os.system('cls')
```

this uses the [system function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/) from the [os library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). this function can do many useful things, one is clearing the screen